# RXJS throw error in a fromPromise does not hit 'catchError' piped method

Tags: rxjs, observable

Can someone explain why this promise (runQuery) , which fails into the 'catch' and throws an ErrorObservable, does not get caught in the 'catchError' method, but goes into 'map' method.
( I tried both _throw/ErrorObservable approach, same result )

```js
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

const runQuery = ( Promise that rejects )

const source$ = fromPromise(
  runQuery({ d: 'g' })
    .catch(err => {
      return new ErrorObservable(err);
      //return _throw(err); -- same as above
    })
  )
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      //ENTERS HERE as response.error     
    }),
    catchError(e => {
      //DOES NOT ENTER
    })
  );
```

Comment: `map` doesn't have any error handler. It works only with `next` notifications. It looks like you have just wrong parenthesis.

Comment: Martin, thank you, you were correct, fixing the parens and doing what Mark said below fixed the issue. thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

You are handling your own error in the promise and let it return an `ErrorObservable`. By doing so you made the promise succeed (although with an error like return value). `fromPromise` will convert this in an emission instead of error.

Remove the catch case in the fromPromise and it should hit the Observable.catchError

Comment: Thank you! that worked.  Like Martin said above, I also had one parens off which what screwing up the pipe method. thanks to you both !!

Answer (score 1):

[I made a live example to prove my point.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-errorhandling?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50)
There is no need to handle the promise (when it is still a promise), so this far from recommendable.

```
.then(data => {
  return data;
})
.catch(err => {
  return new ErrorObservable(err);
  //return _throw(err); -- same as above
}))
```

**Let observables take control of rejections**

```
const source$ = fromPromise(runQuery())        
    .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
            //Make here some transformations
            return response;     
        }),
        catchError(e => {
            return _throw(e);
        }
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the error object or do a console.log() inside the catch in the promise before the observable receives the error you can throw the error:

```
.then(data => {
  return data;
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error("Error", err );
  err.code = 110; // you may want to change something before passing to observable
  throw err;
}))
```

If you use return error the error or catch pipe of the observable won't work, but using throw it works.